# AngularJs: using alias for a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am creating a `reusable library` using `angular`. This library basically associates itself with a `service` provided by the user who uses this library and do some work based on it.

**For example:** There is a service defined in our library called `Login` In which a `User` service is passed through which we check if user is logged in or not.

```
.factory('Login', ['User',
    function(User) {
        return {
            checkLogin: function() {
                //PAGE NOT FOUND ERROR..
                if (User.authenticated) {
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }; //Return
    }
])
```

The `User` service name which I have passed is not fixed could have a different name Like `Employee` or `Customer` its depends on the user as this service is defined by the user who download this library but will have the same function whatever name of service.

Thus, I need some method to map my given formal service name parameter  to actual service name parameter provided by the user.

**For example:**  Some user downloads this library and he has defined the `User` service by the name of `Employee` then my formal service name parameter `User` given maps to the provided actual  service name by some map function.

```
function map(){
   // maps Employee service ==> User service
   /*
      I want this  map  function  to be something this we use in case of a variable like.
      var x = function(){return 1;}
      var y;
      y = x;
      Now y contains the instance of x
      Is something like this possible in case of services? Since services are passed as dependency injection at runtime.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like all you need is dynamic inject, which is possible:

```
    app.factory('Login', ['$injector', function($injector) {
        var service;
        function initService(name) {
            service = $injector.get(name);
        }
    ...
```

And then u use it in service as usual.